# Mysqli Prepared Statements and Transactions Multiple Inserts

Tags: php, mysqli

this post is just to clarify if my code is efficiently written. I need multiple tables to have values inserted within one function. As these values will be submitted via the user I used Prepared statements in order to prevent any SQL injects (the set variables are also effectively cleaned prior to the the function)

```
public function the_name($var1, $var2)
{
  $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
  $stmt_one = $mysqli->prepare("Insert into TABLE SET $var1 = ?, $var2 = ? ");
  $stmt_two = $mysqli->prepare("Insert into TABLE SET $var1 = ?, $var2 = ? ");
  $stmt_one->bind_param('is',$var1,$var2);
  $stmt_two->bind_param('is',$var1,$var2);
  $stmt_one->execute();
  $stmt_two->execute();
  $mysqli->commit();
  $stmt_one->close();
  $stmt_two->close();
}
```

The function works fine, but is this the best way to insert multiple values into two different tables? The function seems long winded... Any clarification if this is in-fact the correct way to write prepared statements with Transactions.

UPDATE:
The function is used to create a notification, upon a user submitting a post to a fellow user. Thus allowing both the post to be inserted in the post table and notification into the notification table.

Comment: Do you insert identical values into 2 different tables?

Comment: @YourCommonSense The values are the same although $stmt_two has an extra value to be inserted (which is just a timestamp)

Comment: Well, your function is inefficient by design, then.

Comment: I updated my question, would you care to elaborate? I should not there are some variances between the two prepared statements. One is inserting the users post and the other is inserting a notification.